# How to detach tmux session using command

Tags: tmux

I want to detach a tmux session. Now I know the shortcut (^b d) but is there a way we can do this via shell command. I am writing an automation script where i need this.

Comment: Skim through the `tmux` manual page; the "CLIENTS AND SESSIONS" section in particular.

Answer (score 10):

Only this:

```
tmux detach
```

Use this link for references: https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux

Answer (score -2):

You can use `git z tmux` in ~/.zshrc.
And use `td`.

Comment: Its not quite clear what these commands do - or if the OP's running zsh